# GPX file analyser for Windows

Tags: windows, gps

I have some GPS log files that i would like to open up and have some program analyse for me. Great if there is a map, shows speed and height-difference :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So will something like [GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/) work for you?